# MySQL: Returning primary key as null

Tags: sql, mysql

```
   SELECT pr.id as process_id, 
          lo.update_time as start_date, 
          REPLACE( sc.message, 'ip.ip.ip.ip', lo.variables ) as message, 
          sc.code 
     FROM logs AS lo 
LEFT JOIN processes AS pr ON lo.process_id = pr.id
LEFT JOIN status_codes AS sc ON lo.status_code_id = sc.code
 ORDER BY lo.id DESC 
    LIMIT 14
```

The issue with that query is that it's returning process_id as all NULL values, even though that's the auto-incremented primary key of that table without any NULL values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `SELECT lo.process_id` not `SELECT pr.id as process_id`

The Rows in which `pr.id` is `NULL` are the ones for which no record exists in the `processes pr` table.

These are kept in because you are using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` rather than an `INNER JOIN`

Answer (score 2):

You're using a [LEFT JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp). Therefore, for every row that exists in either the `logs` or `status_code` tables that doesn't have a corresponding row in the `logs` table, you will get `NULL` values for the corresponding "row" of `processes`.